C++ : A bug in a foreach loop in a function with array input
I'm a beginner and as an exercise I tried to create a function which gets an array of integers as input and returns their maximum.
Here's the code:
#include <iostream>

int maximum(int setOfNumbers[]);

int main()
{
    int a[] = {1, 2};
    std::cout << maximum(a);

    return 0;
}

int maximum(int setOfNumbers[])
{
    int value = setOfNumbers[0];
    for (int n : setOfNumbers)
    {
        value = std::max(n, value);
    }
    return value;
}

and this error is what I receive:
demo.cpp: In function 'int maximum(int*)':
demo.cpp:16:18: error: 'begin' was not declared in this scope; did you mean 'std::begin'?
   16 |     for (int n : setOfNumbers)
      |                  ^~~~~~~~~~~~
      |                  std::begin
In file included from C:/msys64/mingw64/include/c++/13.2.0/string:53,
                 from C:/msys64/mingw64/include/c++/13.2.0/bits/locale_classes.h:40,
                 from C:/msys64/mingw64/include/c++/13.2.0/bits/ios_base.h:41,
                 from C:/msys64/mingw64/include/c++/13.2.0/ios:44,
                 from C:/msys64/mingw64/include/c++/13.2.0/ostream:40,
                 from C:/msys64/mingw64/include/c++/13.2.0/iostream:41,
                 from demo.cpp:1:
C:/msys64/mingw64/include/c++/13.2.0/bits/range_access.h:114:37: note: 'std::begin' declared here
  114 |   template<typename _Tp> const _Tp* begin(const valarray<_Tp>&) noexcept;
      |                                     ^~~~~
demo.cpp:16:18: error: 'end' was not declared in this scope; did you mean 'std::end'?
   16 |     for (int n : setOfNumbers)
      |                  ^~~~~~~~~~~~
      |                  std::end
C:/msys64/mingw64/include/c++/13.2.0/bits/range_access.h:116:37: note: 'std::end' declared here
  116 |   template<typename _Tp> const _Tp* end(const valarray<_Tp>&) noexcept;
      |                                     ^~~

Any idea?
PS: I know there is a way of doing this by the normal for-loop, but I'm interested to find out what's wrong in this foreach-loop and how to fix it.

setOfNumbers is not an array, but rather a pointer. You can't use a range-based for loop on a pointer, because the pointer does not contain any information on the size of the array it points to. See the following question on why setOfNumbers is a pointer, not an array: What is array-to-pointer conversion aka. decay? Note that this only applies to C-style arrays, but not to std::array or std::vector.

The parameter of maximum() is not an arrray. It is a pointer to the first element of an array. You need to pass along the length of the array and use that, or use some other mechanism. (There are several alternatives: std::array, std::vector, template function) Since C++ does not support passing raw arrays to a function, it considers int maximum(int setOfNumbers[]) as alternative notation for int maximum(int* setOfNumbers)

This is actually what std::span is for.

Welcome to StackOverflow @TheBluehameOwl. You can consider to accept the answer most suited for your problem (by clicking the '✔' mark below the score). You can also upvote any helpful answer (see here: What should I do when someone answers my question?).

As mentioned in comments, a range-for loop won't work on your setOfNumbers parameter because it is not the actual array, but rather is a decayed pointer to the 1st element of the array.
To do what you are attempting, you will have to change maximum() to accept a reference to the actual array. Which also means you will have to make maximum() be a template function so it can work with different array sizes, eg:
#include <iostream>

template<size_t N>
int maximum(int (&setOfNumbers)[N])
{
    int value = setOfNumbers[0];
    for (int n : setOfNumbers)
    {
        value = std::max(n, value);
    }
    return value;
}

int main()
{
    int a[] = {1, 2};
    std::cout << maximum(a);

    return 0;
}

Online Demo
The alternative is to change maximum() to work with iterators instead, eg:
#include <iostream>

template<typename Container>
int maximum(const Container &c)
{
    auto iter = std::begin(c);
    int value = *iter;
    while (++iter != std::end(c))
    {
        value = std::max(*iter, value);
    }

    /* alternatively:

    int value = *std::begin(c);
    for (int n : c)
    {
        value = std::max(n, value);
    }
    */

    return value;
}

int main()
{
    int a[] = {1, 2};
    std::cout << maximum(a);

    return 0;
}

Online Demo
Or:
#include <iostream>

template<typename Iterator>
int maximum(Iterator first, Iterator last)
{
    int value = *first;
    while (++first != last)
    {
        value = std::max(*first, value);
    }
    return value;
}

int main()
{
    int a[] = {1, 2};
    std::cout << maximum(a, a+2);
    //or:
    std::cout << maximum(std::begin(a), std::end(a));

    return 0;
}

Online Demo

setOfNumbers is actually a pointer, not an array.
When a is passed as an argument to maximum is decays into a pointer (to the first element in the array).
You cannot use a ranged-based loop with a pointer.
In any case it is not recommended to use raw C arrays in C++.
It is better to use std::vector as your default dynamic array (or std::array for fixed size [and relatively small] ones).
Code example:
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int maximum(std::vector<int> const & setOfNumbers)
{
    int value = setOfNumbers[0];
    for (int n : setOfNumbers)
    {
        value = std::max(n, value);
    }
    return value;
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> a = { 1, 2 };
    std::cout << maximum(a);
}

Output:
2

Note that I passed the vector by const & to avoid a copy, and also ensuring it is not mutated by the function.
Live demo

Note that std:vector and arrays are very different, and that while this approach is functional, it does not answer the question of dealing with arrays. In the original question, memory for the array is on the stack, while vector will go on the heap. This changes the question dramatically.

I agree, but since it seems like the OP would like to support any array size, I thought that using std::vector should be recommended. I believe that using raw C arrays should be discouraged in general.

Here is the implementation using std::span.  The only change from your original implementation is the argument type for maximum.
#include <iostream>
#include <span>

int maximum(std::span<const int> setOfNumbers);

int main()
{
    int a[] = {1, 2};
    std::cout << maximum(a);

    return 0;
}

int maximum(std::span<const int> setOfNumbers)
{
    int value = setOfNumbers[0];
    for (int n : setOfNumbers)
    {
        value = std::max(n, value);
    }
    return value;
}


In your code you have the parameter int setOfNumbers[] which is functionally the same as int* setOfNumbers, you are passing the memory address of the array start, not the actual values of the array. There lies your problem, as that start address does not have any reference to the size. You must pass size in as well, which you can do with a template function to pass size automatically, or as you suggest simply use a standard for loop.
A slight modification to your code should work for you, adding the "template " to your maximum method.
#include <iostream>

template <auto Size>
int maximum(const int (&setOfNumbers)[Size]);

int main()
{
    int a[] = {1, 2};
    std::cout << maximum(a);

    return 0;
}

template <auto Size>
int maximum(const int (&setOfNumbers)[Size])
{
    int value = setOfNumbers[0];
    for (int n : setOfNumbers)
    {
        value = std::max(n, value);
    }
    return value;
}

You will need to build with c++17 or later, e.g. g++ -std=c++17 test.cpp
